# Nothing showing up in php

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this code, nothing shows up.

```
<?php
$host="***********"; // Host name 
$username="**********"; // Mysql username 
$password="***********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="**********"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "ID Number: ". $row['id']. "<br />Name: ". $row["name"]. "<br />Project Status: ". $row["status"]. "<br />Day Started: ". $row["start"]. "<br />Estimated Finish Date: ". $row["finish"]. "<br />Main Phone Number: <a href='tel:". $row["mainphone"]. "'>". $row["mainphone"]. "</a>". "<br />Business Phone Number: <a href='tel:". $row["businessphone"]. "'>". $row["businessphone"]. "</a>". "<br />Home Phone Number: <a href='tel:". $row["homephone"]. "'>". $row["homephone"]. "</a>". "<br />Fax: ". $row["fax"]. "<br />Email Address: ". $row["email"]. "<br />Job Estimate: $". $row["estimate"]. "<br />Job Address: ". $row["address"] ;
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

It comes up a plain white screen. Before I added `while` Everything showed up correctly except for the data it was supposed to pull from SQL. If you could point out any flaws or reasons why it wouldn't be working, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: check log there is error because of that its showing white screen.
enable your error show.
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.